# How can I resolve the "unary operator expected" error in the script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

> expr: syntax error
>   h2.sh: line 13: [: -gt: unary operator expected

```
#!/bin/sh


FILE=merchant.xml

OLDTIME=3600

CURTIME=$date
FILETIME=($date -r File)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)


if ["$TIMEDIFF" -gt "$OLDTIME" ]; then
   echo "File is older, do stuff here" | mail -s "hello" hardik.pahwa@guemstiger.de
fi
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score -1):

please add space here

```
if ["$TIMEDIFF" -gt "$OLDTIME" ]; then
    ^
```

It should be like

```
if [ "$TIMEDIFF" -gt "$OLDTIME" ]; then
```